# Sending data from server to clients using ajax

Tags: ajax, jquery

I have a scenario. i m making a intranet based web application for internal company use.
In which whenever a client updates anything in application.. the other client should be updated .

Steps :

1. One Client update some task .
2. Then server automatically send the updated data to currently connected clients.
3. Hence the client gets updated without sending request to server and checking the changes every now and then.

Please guys give me suggestions how to achieve this.. Any pointer , comments will be really helpful .
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are looking for is called [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29). The basic idea is the following: when the client makes a request, the server keeps the HTTP connection open for a while and only replies when

- either there is some update
- or a fixed time (say one minute) has passed

When the client receives the update, it processes the new data (if any) and immediately asks for another update, and the cycle continues. This is the method used by popular chats over HTTP for instance. You can find more details exploring the above link.

Answer (score 0):

For me if :

Client A send info to server
Client B have to be updated

If Client B uses a web interface, he must send request to be updated. The server cannot send by himself the updated data.

So for me. The client B has to make every 10 sec (for example) a query in ajax (this should be transparent for the user) and if there are new data then update his interface.

Answer (score 0):

You may use SignalR.

Server will have a SignalR hub and client(s) may connect using JavaScript SignalR client.

When one client send data to server. It may either broadcast to all or few clients as an event without the need for clients to fetch data every few seconds.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr

You may even setup a background service on server to push data without any client call.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/background-services?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Answer (score -1):

If it's not paramount this is real time, use an ajax request for each client that checks the server every 10 seconds or so.