# Signage application with Mobile Remote

Tags: javascript, php

My goal is to create a webpage that only displays a full screen video on a TV. Then have a second webpage someone could open up on their mobile device (via a QR code) and have a choice of 4 videos. Once you tap a video on the mobile device, it changes the full screen video on the tv. What is the best way to do this? I was thinking via a MySQL DB storing the webpage, then using JS to check if the content in the DB has been updated, and if it has, make the change on the tv. Is this the best way?

Comment: Your initial idea will definitely work, but there's a chance there might be a more efficient way of doing it. However, I don't think there is anything wrong with updating a value in a DB and changing the video based on that. Speed and performance should be more than acceptable given how simple the setup/data is for this.

Comment: @EssXTee What more efficient way would you recommend? I'm open to ideas! I'm very new to web development and JS particularly, but I'm trying to learn! haha

Comment: I'm not necessarily sure these methods would be more efficient, but one more common method of doing something like this is [Comet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5064527). Another alternative would be simply using a file and having PHP update that with a single value instead of using a Database. Due to the simple and small amount of data, a single file could potentially be more efficient.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.